# How to extract 48*48 icon image from resource of an executable file?

Tags: c++, windows, icons

I can extract 32*32 icon images, but how about 48*48?

I want to extract an icon image with size 48*48 from a .exe file in Windows. At first, I got the icon resource bits and then I used "CreateIconFromResourceEx" API, but it works true for icon images with size 32*32.

Comment: Specify the platform and the type of the file you're reading

Comment: I want to extract an icon image with size 48*48 frome an a .exe file in Windows. 
At first i got the icon resource bits and then i used "CreateIconFromResourceEx" API, but it works true for icon image with size 32*32.

Answer (score 3):

This link includes usefull code in C++ for extracting icon images of an exe or dll file.
but this one dose not work correctly for 48*48 icon image.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/GetIconsfromExeorDLLs/GetIconsfromExeorDLLs_src.zip

this link realy works true for extrancting icon images in various size frome exe or dll files, but this one is written in C#. we can use it to correct the previous one;
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IconExtractor/IconExtractorApp.zip

Answer (score 0):

Use this one for windows:
http://www.resedit.net/

Comment: WHUH? There's only one true ResEdit: ftp://ftp.apple.com/developer/Tool_Chest/Developer_Utilities/ResEdit_2.1.3/

Answer (score 0):

For Windows use the [LoadResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648046(VS.85).aspx) and related Win32 API.  Just name the 48*48 resource something else.

Comment: An icon may contain multiple images in various size. i want to get the application iocn in right size(48*48) for drawing it on a (DC)device context.
I used CreateIconFromResourceEx, but i couldn't get the icon in size 48*48

Comment: @Abolhassan: I understand, and am familiar with the icon file format being a container format, but I'm not sure if there are Win32 API to work with that.  You could try adding a new resource which is only a 48x48 icon.

Answer (score 0):

Icons, images, music and other materials are saved as resources in the EXE file. Executable files often have the PE standard(Portable Executable).
So, simply download a disassembler like "PE Explorer" or "Resource Hacker"
to extract what you want from the executables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code from this perfect answer to list and extract icon size you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20731449/1795050

Also, note that actual resource size icon will be created if you call `CreateIconFromResourceEx` function with zero size and without `LR_DEFAULTSIZE` flag:

```
HICON hIcon = CreateIconFromResourceEx( lpData, dwSize, TRUE, 0x00030000, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
```