# VB.NET - How to correctly load a resource icon with API

Tags: vb.net, api, winapi, resources

I need to extract an icon resource from a file. I have a structure (`Resource`) that contains the byte array, size, find handle, load handle, lock handle (from `FindResource`, `LoadResource` and `LockResource`, respectively).

I know that I need to obtain the Icon handle of my icon. Then I need to use GetIconInfo to retrieve the bit-mask. Then I use `Image.FromHbitmap(h)` to get an image. I then use the dimensions of the image as parameters to `CreateIconFromResourceEx` to retrieve a properly sized Icon.

Does anyone have some code to do this? I can declare all P/Invoke myself. Thanks!

My original code is returning a 32x32 every time.

```
Dim out As ICONINFO
Dim h As IntPtr = res.hLock
GetIconInfo(h, out)
Dim s As Image = Image.FromHbitmap(out.hbmMask)
h = ResourceExplorer.CreateIconFromResourceEx(res.bArray, res.hSize, True, &H30000, s.Width, s.Height, 0)
PictureBox1.Image = Icon.FromHandle(h).ToBitmap
```

Comment: Why not using LoadIcon directly then? Or LoadImage if you want more control over the size and other params? There is a sample here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.fromhicon(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: And some code (C#) to load a resource with LoadImage: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.loadimage

Comment: yes i saw that. problem is i dont know size of my resource. this is what i need help with (by size i mean dimensions)

Comment: Icons have predefined sizes, the most common are 16x16 and 32x32. With LoadImage you can load the size you need for your purpose. You can also check the LoadIconWithScaleDown function on Vista and above. Otherwise, if you need to enumerate available icon dimensions in the resource you might check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20729156/find-out-number-of-icons-in-an-icon-resource-using-win32-api